# Attack on RSA and ECC

Tags: rsa, ecc

I am reading information about RSA and Eliptic Curves cryptography. Assuming that both these two algorithms have stages until two parts achieve key exchange. If an attacker eavesdrop the stages before achieving successful key exchange, and more specifically in wireless nodes, can't he manage to read/eavesdrop critical information in order to get the secret keys?

Comment: I believe you are asking about key exchange algorithms, like Diffie-Hellman, which allows to create a secret shared key between two parties even in the face of eavesdropping. Check out explanations on the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange and that should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to Elliptical Curve Diffie Hellman (ECDH) key exchange, the answer is no, because the only information that goes over the wire is the users' **public** keys.  See the diagram below:

[image]

As you can see, after Alice and Bob exchange their public keys, Bob computes the shared secret by multiplying his **private** key and Alice's **public** key.  Alice does the same thing, she multiplies her **private** key and Bob's **public** key.  They arrive at the same shared secret.  But, someone eavesdropping on the connection would not be able to compute the shared secret, because that person would not have knowledge of either party's private key.